# woocommerce payment gateway callback not firing

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am struggling making a woocommerce gateway for cofidis. This institution needs that I post via form a set of variables and after confirmation is made, it sends back, via get a set of variables informing if the operation was successful. So following the woocommerce documentation and google and stackoverflow, and many other sites, I am stucked.
Here is my code:

```
function cofidis_init_gateway_class() {

    class WC_Cofidis_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        private $SUCCESS_CALLBACK_URL = "cofidis_payment_success";
        private $FAILURE_CALLBACK_URL = "cofidis_payment_failure";
        private $REJECTED_CALLBACK_URL = "cofidis_payment_rejected";
        private $CONFIRM_CALLBACK_URL = "cofidis_payment_confirm";
        private $SUCCESS_REDIRECT_URL = "/checkout/order-received/";
        private $FAILURE_REDIRECT_URL = "/checkout/order-received/";
        private $API_HOST = " ";
        private $API_SESSION_CREATE_ENDPOINT = "/checkout/v1/session/create";


        /**
         * Constructor for the gateway.
         */
        public function __construct() {

            $this->id                 = 'cofidis';
            $this->icon               = '';
            $this->has_fields         = true;
            $this->method_title       = 'Finance your shopping with cofidis';
            $this->method_description = 'Allows finnancing as a method of payment. Orders are marked as "on-hold" when received.';

            $this->supports = array('products');

            // Method with all the options fields.
            $this->init_form_fields();

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_settings();
            $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->description = $this->get_option( 'description' );
            $this->enabled = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );

            //Get the local server url
            $this->siteUrl = get_site_url();

            //Testmode property stores if we are in test mode or not.
            $this->testmode = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'testmode' ); 

            //If we are in test mode we store test field values if not we store normal fields
            $this->url_cofidis = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_url_cofidis' ) : $this->get_option( 'url_cofidis' );
            $this->vendor_code = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_vendor_code' ) : $this->get_option( 'vendor_code' );
            $this->product_code = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_product_code' ) : $this->get_option( 'product_code' );

            // We need custom JavaScript to obtain a token
            //add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'payment_scripts' ) );

            // Actions
            // This action hook saves the settings
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

            //register the callback hooks which we will use to receive the payment response from the gateway.
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_'. $this->SUCCESS_CALLBACK_URL, array( $this, 'payment_success'));
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . $this->FAILURE_CALLBACK_URL, array( $this, 'payment_failure'));
            add_action ('woocommerce_api_' . $this->REJECTED_CALLBACK_URL, array( $this, 'payment_rejected'));
            add_action ('woocommerce_api_' . $this->CONFIRM_CALLBACK_URL, array( $this, 'payment_confirm'));    
        }



 private function payment_success($order_id) {
     //Do something
     var_dump($order_id)
    }
```

According to that, everytime I call 'url: mysite.com/wc-api/cofidis_payment_success, it should trigger the payment_success method, but I can't achive that instead I allways get a white page with -1.
Is that I am understanding this wrong?

Comment: I'm currently stuck in the same situation. Did you succeed in solving this?

Comment: @NunoJMSantos This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/226912)

Comment: 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here, for dev help with WooCommerce and 3rd party APIs you need to contact their support routes

Comment: Hi. I didn't know about the reward, I'll read it. On the other hand, I don't agree that this is off topic. Wordpress also has an extensive support system, but this site should not be discarded for that. This is for learning and I don't think this question is irrelevant.